# Email Regex is not working for multiple values in a string message

Tags: java, regex

Below is my code, I want to mask emails present in my string.

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String email = "riyajose@gmail.com your my rosymj@gmail.com";
        String regex="(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\\G)[^@]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String mask="$1*"; // String maskedEmail = email.replaceAll("\\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}\\b", "xxxxxx");
        String  email1 = pattern.matcher(email).replaceAll(mask);
        System.out.println("email : "+email);
        System.out.println("maskedEmail : "+email1);
    }
 }
```

The issue with above code is for the first email id its masking second one not. How to fix this

Comment: It should be something like `String regex="((?<!\\S)[^\\s@]{3}|(?!^)\\G)[^\\s@](?=[^@\\s]*@)";`. Or with `\\b` instead of `(?<!\\S)` if your matches must always start with a word char. See https://ideone.com/GfQUPm

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*` regular expression will match both `riyajose@gmail.com` and `rosymj@gmail.com` in your string, leaving "your my" unmatched. If you don't want to match the domain, just use `[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@`, which will match the ending `@` too

Comment: ...but do not use the regex in Java, its regex engine is not reliable with such patterns when using them against long texts.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to mask emails present in my string ..."*

Try a *match pattern*, and the *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* class.

```
\b[^ ]+?(?=@)
```

Here is an example.

```java
StringBuilder email = new StringBuilder("riyajose@gmail.com your my rosymj@gmail.com");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[^ ]+?(?=@)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
while (m.find()) email.replace(m.start(), m.end(), "x".repeat(m.group().length()));
```

Output

```
xxxxxxxx@gmail.com your my xxxxxx@gmail.com
```